# Kibana dashboard - user authentication

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-plugin, kibana-5

How to setup user authentication for my kibana dashboard. Actually i need two login 
1. admin 2. user . admin - view all left hand side menu like (discover,Visualizer ,dev tools and so on.) user - only Dashboard. i am using 6.3 version of kibana . Would be great any references or steps to follow

Comment: Do you see `Management` on the left - Select that and click on Security? you should be logged in as an admin.

Comment: I couln't find security in management

Comment: Ok. I believe, you need to login with elastic username.

Comment: http://localhost:5601/app/kibana - it is not asking me to login.. how to anble login screen? is it really required to install x-pack in 6.3.0 version

Comment: I don't work with kibana too match but I only see when install x-pack plugin a login page appear when open localhost:5601 and I don't see any user level in x-pack

Comment: How did you implement .. how to install x-plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Xpack is available since 6.8/7.1.

See https://www.elastic.co/blog/security-for-elasticsearch-is-now-free